# How can I set native query results to dynatable

Tags: json, database, hibernate, dynatable

I want to set my native query results to http://www.dynatable.com/ directly but this library require me to use json like the following

[
  {
    "band": "Weezer",
    "song": "El Scorcho"
  },
  {
    "band": "Chevelle",
    "song": "Family System"
  }
]

but the result of my native query is just a list of lists so I don't have the column name in it ... How can I solve that ?